# How can I use CSS to center text in DIV

Tags: css

I need to create upload button that centered at an image.
I'm a beginner, please help and explain how to use. Many thanks.

Here is my code:
https://jsfiddle.net/marco83/ydgnkfw3/

**HTML**

```
<div class="media-left text-center container22">
    <img src="http://images.buddytv.com/btv_2_505531673_0_1200_10000_-1_/the-pacific-james-ba.jpg" style="width: 150px; height: 150px;" class="image1"></img>
  <a href="#" id="upfile1">
  <span style="font-size: 28px;" id="img-upload-bt" class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera"></span>
  </a>
</div>
<input type="file" id="file1"  name="file1" style="display:none" />
```

**CSS**

```
.container22 {
   height: 10em;
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: middle;
   text-align: center;
}
#upfile1 {
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
}
```

**Here is what i want**
[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to align text vertically center in div with CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865458/how-to-align-text-vertically-center-in-div-with-css)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to make the parent container `relative` and use position `absolute` for the inner element you're trying to center:

```
.image-container {
  position: relative;
}
#img-upload-bt {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin: -14px 0 0 -14px;
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ydgnkfw3/2/)**

Comment: thanks, chosen this answer because i also want to use `img` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the css `position` property of the parent element to `relative` and `img` to `position:absolute`. Then you use css properties of `top, bottom, left and right` to position the image.

```
.container22 {
   height: 10em;
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: middle;
   text-align: center;
   position:relative;
}
#upfile1 {
   position: absolute;
   left:55px;
    top:55px;
}
```

[See an example here](https://jsfiddle.net/qdopL8b4/).

Answer (score 0):

The image pushes the icon out of the way
Use background image instead

```
.container22{
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    background-image:url('http://images.buddytv.com/btv_2_505531673_0_1200_10000_-1_/the-pacific-james-ba.jpg');
    background-size:150px 150px;
    background-position:center top;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    padding-right:0
```

}

https://jsfiddle.net/marco83/ydgnkfw3/

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to handle this would be to just set the image as a background-image in the css, if that's something your particular situation allows for -

```
.container22 {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    background: url("http://images.buddytv.com/btv_2_505531673_0_1200_10000_-1_/the-pacific-james-ba.jpg") center center no-repeat;
}
```

That + removing the image tag for the markup will create the look you want.

If you have to use the image inline, you can put `position:relative` on the container element, and position either the image or the upload glyph span with `position: absolute` - note that you may have to force a width and height on the container if you set that on the image. If you set it on the glyph span, you'll also need `left:0; right:0; margin: auto;` to center it.